# Nine figures in a single slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I am trying to insert nine images into a single slide in Beamer.

This is how I have done it for four images:

```
\begin{frame}{Introduzione}
  \begin{columns}[t]
     \column{.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{img1.png}\\
     \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{img2.png}
     \column{.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{img3.jpeg}\\
     \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{img4.png}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

How can I extend this to get three images in one row, three more in another row and the last three in the last row of the slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main suggestion is to use relative, not absolute, sizes. And. use either `\medskip` or `\bigskip` to insert some vertical whitespace between the figures in a column.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % remove "demo" option in real document
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduzione}
  \begin{columns}[t]
     \column{.32\linewidth} % 3*0.32 = 0.96 < 1...
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img1.png}

     \bigskip
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img2.png}

     \bigskip
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img3.png}

     \column{.32\linewidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img4.png}

     \bigskip
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img5.png}

     \bigskip
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img6.png}

     \column{.32\linewidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img7.png}

     \bigskip
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img8.png}

     \bigskip
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight]{img9.png}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fit 9 images on a slide by making the columns smaller, i.e. if they should have the same sizes make them less than `0.33\textwidth`.

To make scaling if the images easier, you could scale them relative to the column widths instead of absolute numbers. But please only give either the width of the height, otherwise the aspect ratio of the image will be distorted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduzione}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{column}    
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]